# When is an intersection of quadrics empty

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Is there an easy way to tell when the intersection of a set of quadrics (in complex projective space) is empty? Assume you know the quadrics explicitly.

Comment: Elimination Theory. This is implemented in the modern Computer Algebra systems, such as *Singular* and *Macaulay2*.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted general criterion, since I have an infinite family of intersections. I know it's not empty in low dimensions using the aforementioned software.